# nginx rate limit not working

Tags: android, nginx

I have a simple nginx config with access rate limiting, however the rate limit only works for / location, not for /android/ nor /ios/, can any one help, thanks. For example, app.xyz.com is limited, but app.xyz.com/android/abc/de/s.apk not limited. Thanks for explanation.

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" ' '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" ' '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/m;
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  app.xyz.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2;
        server_name  app.xyz.com;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/www.access.log  main;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.xyz.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.xyz.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
            limit_req zone=one burst=3 nodelay;
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /android/ {
            limit_req zone=one burst=3 nodelay;
        }

        location /ios/ {
            limit_req zone=one burst=3 nodelay;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You are sending the files for `/android/` and `/ios/` from `$NGINX_PREFIX/html` since you are not defining`root`. I believe that your problem is much more related to that than anything else.  That said, if you want to limit_req everything you should disable `sendfile` since that will not pass though nginx buffers and will not limit anything.